# Supervisord as Windows Service on Cygwin

Tags: windows-services, cygwin, celery, daemon, supervisord

I am attempting to run Celery as a Windows Service using Supervisord. I followed the configuration laid out on the Celery site and [here][1]. I have set up a virtual environment to run supervisord through cygwin.I have highlighted the lines I think are most important (with **). It appears supervisord and rabbitMQ are working. The problem is with Celery.

I setup the service with the commands:

```
$ cygrunsrv --install supervisord --path  /usr/bin/python --args "/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /usr/etc/supervisord.conf"
$ supervisord
```

**UPDATED:** I now have the following in my supervisord.log file:

```
2014-08-07 12:46:40,676 INFO exited: celery (exit status 1; not expected) 
2014-08-07 12:47:07,187 INFO Increased RLIMIT_NOFILE limit to 1024 
2014-08-07 12:47:07,238 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized 
2014-08-07 12:47:07,251 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process 
2014-08-07 12:47:07,253 INFO supervisord started with pid 7508 
2014-08-07 12:47:08,272 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 8056 
**2014-08-07 12:47:08,833 INFO success: celery entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)**
```

The config file is:

```
    [inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
port=127.0.0.1:8072       ; (ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface)
username = user
password = 123

[supervisord]
logfile= /home/HBA/venv/logFiles/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
;user=HBA                 ; (default is current user, required if root)
childlogdir=/tmp            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)


[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:8072 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket

[program:celery]
command= celery worker -A runLogProject --loglevel=INFO              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
directory= /home/HBA/venv/runLogProject
environment=PATH="/home/HBA/venv/;/home/HBA/venv/Scripts/"
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile= /home/HBA/venv/logFiles/%(program_name)s/worker.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile= /home/HBA/venv/logFiles/%(program_name)s/worker.log        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=1000
killasgroup=true
```

My celery log file gives me:

```
    **[2014-08-07 19:46:40,584: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-4' pid:12284 exited with 'signal -1'
[2014-08-07 19:46:40,584: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-3' pid:4432 exited with 'signal -1'
[2014-08-07 19:46:40,584: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-2' pid:9120 exited with 'signal -1'
[2014-08-07 19:46:40,584: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-1' pid:6280 exited with 'signal -1'**
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\worker.py:161: CDeprecationWarning: 
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))

[2014-08-07 19:47:08,822: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\worker.py:161: CDeprecationWarning: 
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))

**[2014-08-07 19:47:08,944: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2014-08-07 19:47:08,954: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-08-07 19:47:09,963: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone**
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:236: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2014-08-07 19:47:09,982: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:236: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2014-08-07 19:47:09,982: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@CORONADO ready.
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please let me know if there is anyway I could improve it to improve clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using the following command: /home/HBA/venv/Scripts/celery worker -A runLogProject --loglevel=INFO

My biggest issue was an unfamiliarity with virtual environments. I needed to make sure the files were in the correct folders within the venv.